# CSS Changes to table class do not occour

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to define a table class and change some of its properties, but nothing occurs. Each cell in my table should contain an image 50x52, with no spacing in between. However, there are spacing and the image size needs to be defined manually each time.

My code:

```css
table.gameboard
{
  width: 500px;
  height: 520px;
  border: 1px solid #000000; /* Added By Editor */
  border-collapse: collapse; /* Added By Editor */
}
table.gameboard td 
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 52px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #000000; /* Added By Editor */
}
```

```html
<table class="gameboard">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="blank.bmp"  width=50 height=52  id="puzzle0x0"></td>
    <td><img src="blank.bmp"  width=50 height=52  id="puzzle0x1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="blank.bmp"  width=50 height=52  id="puzzle19x18"></td>
    <td><img src="blank.bmp"  width=50 height=52  id="puzzle19x19"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If I remove the manual definition of the width and height, the image becomes larger, despite the gameboard's td definition of 50px x 52px. Also, there are spaces, when there should not be.

I am not sure if the `<style type='text/css'>` should be defined under `<head>` or `<body>`, I tried either option, to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: tables are curious things to style.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <style>
        table.gameboard td 
            {
                width: 50px;
                height: 52px;
                border-spacing: 0px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
         table.gameboard td img
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
    </style>
```

try this style, it will work

Comment: The 'td img' does affect the image size, but the spacing between the lines or columns remain, its like the 'td' does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

style and `<link>` alwasy goes in head tag

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some CSS settings were needed to be reset. The changes are:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

and also for image:

```
table.gameboard td img
                            {
                border: 0px;
                            width: 50px;
                            height: 52px;
                border-spacing: 0;
                display: block;
                            }
```

I'm pretty sure not all resets are required, but not sure which one of them I needed.